# Proof explanation: "Every convergent sequence is bounded"

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am looking at this proof:

Let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence with $a_n \to a$. Choose $\varepsilon =1$, then there is a $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.
$$|a_n|=|(a_n-a)+a|\leq |a_n-a|+|a|<1+|a| \quad \text{for all } n\geq N$$

Choose $A:=\max\{1+|a|, |a_1|, ..., |a_{N-1}|\}$. It follows that $|a_n|\leq A$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

I don't understand what $A:=\max\{1+|a|, |a_1|, ..., |a_{N-1}|\}$ means or why one would choose $A$ like that. That's a problem I'm always facing with different proofs.

Comment: At that point in the proof, we already know that $|a_n| < 1 + |a|$ for all $n \geq N$, so we have almost shown the sequence is bounded. The hard part is over. But, we still have to worry about $a_1, \ldots, a_{N-1}$. We need to find an upper bound that works for all numbers in the sequence, including $a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}$.

Comment: it means the maximum of the numbers $1+|a|,|a_1|,\dots,|a_{n_0}-1|$, i.e., whichever is biggest

Comment: Hey littleO, brilliant explanation. But how do we know what $N$ is? Is $N$ arbitrary?

Comment: The definition of convergent sequence guarantees that if you give me an $\epsilon$, I can find an $N$ that works. So it's not arbitrary, my choice of it was forced by your choice of $\epsilon$.

Comment: By the definition of convergence, we *chose* the $N$ for which $|a_n-a|<1$ for $n > N$.

Comment: But we don't really know what $N$ is, do we?

Comment: As in, we don't know that it's 500, yeah, that's right. We just have a guarantee that we can find one that will work.

Comment: Okay, that's why we include $|a_1|, ... |a_{N-1}|$. I understand now, thank you guys for your amazing help!

Answer (score 2):

The proof argument here basically is

That if $\{a_n\}$ converges to limit a there will be an index $N_1$ from which
upwards  the sequence is bounded by the constant $1+|a|$

This is  used then to imply the boundedness for all terms of the sequence $\{a_n\}$.

Since we know that there are only finitely many terms of the sequence 
(all $a_n$ with $n<N_1$) which possibly can be  greater than the constant $1+|a|$,
we have nothing more  to do than to choose the maximum out of these numbers
$a_1$ to $a_{N_1}$, $1+|a|$ and this will be an upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

This is an outline of the proof to give you some orientation.

We have a convergent sequence. Then we cut it into two -- the initial part which has a finite number of terms, and the tail with infinitely many parts. Since it converges, we can choose the tail so that all terms in the tail are a distance of one or less from the limit. With this we can show that this tail is bounded by manipulating inequalities.

Finally, we consider the first (finite) part. Since it is a finite set of real numbers, it must have a minimum and maximum number. The maximum number is chosen as an upper bound for the head. Finally, we want to join the head to the tail. Then it makes sense (doesn't it?) to take the bigger of the two bounds (the one for the head and the other for the tail) as the upper bound for the whole sequence, and we are done.